# Why same sample have different loudness in FL and Live?

Tags: ableton-live, fl-studio

I loaded same sample (Kick) in FL v20.x and Ableton Live v10.x, in FL the volume is around `-8db` and in Live is around `-6db`, why?

Answer (score 1):

It’s almost certain that Live and FL have different metering algorithms for their channels and/or busses. Also the summing algorithms and panning laws are probably different.

Comment: Good info, is this documented some where? I see you wrote almost/probably so I think you are not sure about that, am I right?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani They don’t seem to describe their meter algorithms in the documentation, but it does seem like the FL default meter is peak only while the Live meter is combined peak & RMS. One important aspect of a meter is its *integration time*. Especially with percussion noises, the levels shown on meters can vary greatly between different integration times. There’s no standard for meter integration time so there’s no reason to expect any two meters to use the same one. Also with 32 bit audio as is used in both, there’s no expectation of using the same calibration point.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I wonder why you would expect the two meters to show the same thing in the first place. That’s like expecting two different cars to have the same size glove box or two different restaurants to have the same chairs. Meters are not some standard thing that work exactly the same in every software package. Pro Tools has something like ten different metering algorithms to choose from. Just cause FL and Live don’t say which ones they are using doesn’t mean we should assume they are using the same one.

Comment: I think I should mentioned couple of thing here, 1. I check the loudness using `FabFilter Pro-L 2`, that's why I expected same value in both. 2. I think -3db is important, because if I want to hear same thing in FL as I hear in Live, I should change the Master volume, or PC's volume, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's due to different panning laws
https://www.gearslutz.com/board/music-computers/814978-fl-circular-triangular-panning-law-other-daws-getting-clear-mixes.html

Try switching the panning law between "triangular" vs "circular" in FL Studio.
https://www.image-line.com/support/flstudio_online_manual/html/songsettings_settings.htm

Comment: +1 for the links, thanks. but as I mentioned in above answer's comment, is this documented or your answer is based on mentioned link?

Comment: Did you try changing the setting in FL Studio? Do you think the FL Studio reference manual I linked to doesn't qualify as documentation? Did you read what it says?

Comment: I changed the setting and nothing changes, still same value. yes I read both links and some other articles, now I know that FL and Live uses different panning law

Comment: @MehdiDehghani if the pan law setting doesn't do what the manual says it does, then it's a bug and you should file a bug report at ImageLine / FL Studio

Comment: Did you try to change the setting, if so, did you see the change which is mentioned in the docs?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani no I don't have FL Studio. Contact ImageLine's support, that's what it is for https://www.image-line.com/support/